# How to encode cyrillic characters for URL and then decode them?

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I have a form on one page:

```
<form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="index.cgi" name="TestForm">
```

One of the input fields "search_string" may be used to send Cyrillic characters and if that happens the URL string looks like this:

```
search_string=%41F%2F%424+%41F%41E%414%416%410%420%41A%410+%418%417+%421%412%418%41D
```

How do I decode this back to the original string on the page I post to?

Comment: Looks like hexadecimal data that was then url encoded.. What is the original string?

Answer (score 5):

Correct solution, including spaces:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use Encode;

my $escaped = '%41F%2F%424+%41F%41E%414%416%410%420%41A%410+%418%417+%421%412%418%41D';
(my $unescaped = $escaped) =~ s/\+/ /g;
$unescaped =~ s/%([[:xdigit:]]+)/chr hex $1/eg;
print $unescaped;
# П/Ф ПОДЖАРКА ИЗ СВИН
```

Credit goes to [Renaud Bompuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811/renaud-bompuis) for recognising as the first that these are Unicode code-points prefixed with `%`.

I wish to add that the encoding scheme from the question is very unusual, I haven't seen it before. Normally one would expect the characters string `П/Ф ПОДЖАРКА ИЗ СВИН` to be encoded as `%D0%9F%2F%D0%A4+%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%96%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%9A%D0%90+%D0%98%D0%97+%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%98%D0%9D`, that is to say, first the characters are encoded into UTF-8, then the octets are percent-escaped. This scheme works with the answer from [Dr.Kameleon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270812/dr-kameleon).

Answer (score 2):

A solution that preserves the `+` and any other character in the original string:

```
my $s = '%41F%2F%424+%41F%41E%414%416%410%420%41A%410+%418%417+%421%412%418%41D';
$s =~ s/%([[:xdigit:]]+)/chr(hex($1))/eg;
print $s;
```

Result:

```
П/Ф+ПОДЖАРКА+ИЗ+СВИН
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that in your script (`index.cgi`) :

```
use Encode;
```

Then...

```
$search_string = decode_utf8( $search_string );
```

---

Another idea (if you want to create a UTF8-friendly hash of your CGI input) :

```
require Encode;
require CGI;
my $query = CGI ->new;
my $form_input = {};  
foreach my $name ( $query ->param ) {
  my @val = $query ->param( $name );
  foreach ( @val ) {
    $_ = Encode::decode_utf8( $_ );
  }
  $name = Encode::decode_utf8( $name );
  if ( scalar @val == 1 ) {   
    $form_input ->{$name} = $val[0];
  } else {                      
    $form_input ->{$name} = \@val;  # save value as an array ref
  }
}
```

Taken from : http://ahinea.com/en/tech/perl-unicode-struggle.html

Comment: Well, using the decode_utf8() resulted in "AF/B4 AFAEA4A6A0B0AAA0 A8A7 B1A2A8AD" string which is not the original Cyrillic string I entered.