# Is cgi->param using a uri_unescape by default?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, internationalization, cgi

I use `$cgi->param('search_string');` to retrieve a url parameter in my Perl script but I suspect that the `$cgi->param` value is being passed through `uri_unescape()` function before I get it.

Example:

1. The form has a `search_string=ЛИКЕР ВИШНЕВЫЙ`
2. The url has a `search_string=%41B%418%41A%415%420+%412%418%428%41D%415%412%42B%419`
3. But the `$cgi->param('search_string')` returns `ABA8AAA5B0+A2A8B8ADA5A2BBA9` rather than `%41B%418%41A%415%420+%412%418%428%41D%415%412%42B%419` which I could simply decode.

Here's what actually takes place in my code:

I pass this "ПЛЕНКА ПИЩЕВАЯ" as the $search_string;

```
$search_string =~ s/\s/+/g;
$search_string =~ s/\#/\%23/g;
$search_string =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\*\.\@\_\-]/uc sprintf("%%%02x",ord($&))/egx;
```

From that I get this `search_string=%41F%41B%415%41D%41A%410+%41F%418%429%415%412%410%42F` in the URL itself.

Then when I use `$cgi->param('search_string')` to retrieve that value on the other end and I get this `"AFABA5ADAAA0 AFA8B9A5A2A0BF"`. The additional issue here is that it seems that $cgi->param('search_string') does call uri_unescape() automatically, that's why I get `"AFABA5ADAAA0 AFA8B9A5A2A0BF"`.

How do I make it so that the end result comes back to me as `"ПЛЕНКА ПИЩЕВАЯ"`?

Comment: Show some code, which reproduces this behaviour. You may have probems with encodings, not with CGI methods.

Comment: [goe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1164818/goe) uses [something that does not follow the relevant standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818988/how-to-encode-cyrillic-characters-for-url-and-then-decode-them).

Comment: I added my code to the question, please advise if you know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going on, I put together the following CGI script:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI;
use Encode;

run();

sub run {
    my $cgi = CGI->new;
    if ( $cgi->param ) {
        show_result($cgi);
    }
    else {
        show_form($cgi);
    }
}

sub show_result {
    my $cgi = shift;

    my $search_term = decode('UTF-8', $cgi->param('search_term') );

    print $cgi->header(
        -type => 'text/plain',
        -charset => 'UTF-8',
    ), $search_term, "\n";
}

sub show_form {
    my $cgi = shift;
    print $cgi->header(
        -type => 'text/html',
        -charset => 'UTF-8',
    ),
    <<EO_HTML;
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search" id="search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<p>Search term: <input type="text" name="search_term" id="search_term"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</body>
</html>
EO_HTML
}
```

Now, when I run this and copy & paste *ЛИКЕР ВИШНЕВЫЙ* into the input field, I get the exact same string echoed back to me.

Firefox's location field actually shows: `http://test.localdomain:8080/cgi-bin/test.pl?search_term=ЛИКЕР+ВИШНЕВЫЙ` but copying and pasting that string into this textbox gives me `http://test.localdomain:8080/cgi-bin/test.pl?search_term=%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%A0+%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A8%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%99`

Comment: Sidenote: `use CGI "-utf8"` can replace the manual `Encode::decode` step on `param`s.

Comment: Except that `perldoc CGI` states *This makes `CGI.pm` treat all parameters as UTF-8 strings. Use this with care, as it will interfere with the processing of binary uploads. It is better to manually select which fields are expected to return utf-8 strings and convert them using code like this:*