# Internet Explorer cyrillic symbols parameter in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, encoding

I'm writing an MVC4 Web Application. And I have one issue, when I use some custom URL with parameters, what is with cyrillic symbols, it's not display correctly in IE ( any version ). But in anather browsers all OK!
Example:

```
http://192.168.241.87:8085/Home/Person?name=Андрей
```

it's looks like this:

```
http://192.168.241.87:8085/Home/Person?name=??????
```

P.S. I can't handle how to create a URL link. And i tryed to handle it with encoding on server side ( with `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, globalization parameters `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" />` and tryig to encode it with javascript) - but it's not works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question may have been answered in another post. Did you find the solution? Please try this answer in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818988/how-to-encode-cyrillic-characters-for-url-and-then-decode-them)

Comment: Thanks Robert. I did find a solution, almost similar to this one.

Comment: What solution did you find?